# How to select all columns with Doctrine QueryBuilder?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have the entities **Store**, **Owner** and **Town** and i want to **count all the stores** that an owner has, categorized by their Town.

I have this Query in my Controller

```
$query = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('WebBundle:Store')
   ->createQueryBuilder('s')
     ->select('t.name, COUNT(s) as counter')
     ->groupBy('s.town')
     ->leftJoin('s.owner','o')
     ->leftJoin('s.town','t')
     ->where('s.owner = :id')
     ->orderBy('t.name','ASC')
     ->setParameter('id', $id)
  ->getQuery();

$list = $query->getResult();
```

Is there any way to **select all columns from Town** instead of declaring every column? Something like `->select('t.*, COUNT(s) as counter')`. I can select the ones i need now, but for larger tables I will need other method.

I've tried `->select('t, COUNT(s) as counter')` but I got an exception error.

For further information, in my twig template i want to show this:

```
{% for town in list %}
    <span>{{ town.name }}</b> [{{ town.counter }}]</span>
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks for all in advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you have some relations in your entities.

`Owner` must have a 1-n relation with `Store`.

So, your `Owner` entity will be looks like this :

```
class Owner
{
    protected $stores;

    // ...

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->stores = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getStores()
    {
        return $this->stores;
    }

    public function setStores($stores)
    {
        $this->stores = new ArrayCollection();

        foreach ($stores as $store)
        {
            $this->stores->add($store);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function addStore(Store $store) // ... can use $this->store->add()

    public function removeStore(Store $store) // ... can use $this->store->removeElement()

    // etc ...

}
```

So now, you can use the `Collection::count()` Doctrine method !

```
$storesCnt = $user->getStores()->count();
```

You want to get all stores for a user and a town ?
No problem ! `Collection::filter()` is your friend !

```
$storesForAUserAndAGivenTown = $user->getStores()->filter(function (Store $store) use ($town) {
    return ($store->getTown() === $town);
});
```

That's it.

Consider the first rule of Doctrine is `Forget the database !`, so use DQL or QueryBuilder only and only if it's necessary.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Excelent! This helps a lot.. Thanks for your answer!!

Comment: Terrible suggestion... Never forget database. You can do stuff way faster in database with good queries, rather 10 level wrapper. And your filter requires database to fetch all stores to compare them for town name. I guess you never seen what s**ty queries doctrine does.

Comment: @ErnestasStankevičius Sure I agree 100% that the database should never forget. But an ORM solution is not really used for performances (or just if you want to use it for the db creation). 
Better way is to know how and when use the ORM layer correctly, and when use the db layer. 
In my opinion, a correct usage of the ORM layer will make your project progress faster in terms of development and unit testing. With a lower impact on performances.

Finally, in this context, the most elegant solution was to get data from retrieved entity, if this was not lazy loaded.

Answer (score 2):

You can select all by omitting the column name like or the match-all wild-card. So, instead of t.name or t.*, you can simply do t Like So:

```
        $query = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('WebBundle:Store')
              ->createQueryBuilder('s')
              ->select('t, COUNT(s) AS counter')
              ->groupBy('s.town')
              ->leftJoin('s.owner','o')
              ->leftJoin('s.town','t')
              ->where('s.owner = :id')
              ->orderBy('t.name','ASC')
              ->setParameter('id', $id)
              ->getQuery();

            $list = $query->getResult();
```